# How to use Yeoman with Bourbon rather than Compass?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, gruntjs, yeoman, bourbon

How would I go about setting up Yeoman + Grunt.js to compile Sass without Compass? I'd like to use thoughtbot's [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/) rather than Compass. Would I need to create a custom generator for this or is it a matter of passing a flag to the already existing Yeoman generators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your directory:

1. `npm uninstall grunt-contrib-compass --save-dev` (removes compass from node_modules and package.json)
2. `npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev` (adds sass to node_modules and package.json)

Open up Gruntfile.js

1. In the `watch` task (around line 22) change "compass" to "scripts"
2. Change the `compass` task (around line 109) to "sass" then format according to the [grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) docs. My gruntfile [gruntfile.js gist](https://gist.github.com/bhuizi/7592075).
3. Run a find and replace "compass" to "sass"
4. Install Bourbon

Answer (score 5):

You can just switch out the [grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass) task with [grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) and then follow the Bourbon [install instructions](http://bourbon.io).